# Blowing air on a thin film

Tags: visible-light, interference

Today I was bathing, when I decided to experiment with thin films. I took some transparent soap on my index finger and thumb gap, and created a thin film. Initially I saw the usual interference pattern one might see (rainbow color type bands). But then, I, for no particular reason decided to blow air on it through my mouth. This led to a very interesting experience!

I was blowing air on the sides of the thin film to appropriately mix everything. Initially, things weren't that good and I got random brown color patches in a turbulent thin film (viscous flow in a thin film!) the whole thing was very randomized and looked like this, except the background was transparent and the colors were that of a rainbow band. Certainly interesting, but not surprising. (Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference)
[image]

However the surprising thing came when I blowed air on it long enough as it kept on spinning, with little noticeable turbulence. It started getting uniform colors throughout the film! Initially I saw pinkish-violet color, and upon blowing further (I barely changed the angles, and maybe this un-noticeable change could be the reason but there were moments where I just blowed on the film and some part changed colors but the other part remained the same... weird right?) the colors kept on changing until the film got burst. The order of the colors I saw was

Pinkish Violet,
Very deep blue,
Less deep blue,
Green (the kind you'd see on leaves),
Brownish-yellow

and... then the film (sadly) burst. The interesting thing is this order is approximately that of VIBGYOR, the rainbow's band.

I repeated the experiment several times (6 to be precise) and noticed similar results, although I couldn't get past the Yellow mark.

My question is, is there anything to explain this particular phenomenon? I couldn't figure why would this happen! And

Comment: I'm guessing, but it sounds like the blowing happens to cause it to dry up in a rather uniform way, so that the thickness is uniformly just enough for those specific interference patterns.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Starting with I'm guessing, I'm not comfortable posting it as an answer, and also, it is so dayum short!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optics of thick soap bubbles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466127/optics-of-thick-soap-bubbles) with blowing making the film thinner.

Comment: Thanks, this does.